# Issue in creating a html file from beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Here is the my python code using BeautifulSoup. The main issue is with the  attributes. What I am looking for is, each element of the th should be separated but for some reason it keep generating inside only one individual tag.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag
soup=BeautifulSoup()
mem_attr=['Description','PhysicalID','Slot','Size','Width']
tag1 = Tag(soup, "html")
tag2 = Tag(soup, "table")
tag3 = Tag(soup, "tr")
tag4 = Tag(soup, "th")
tag5 = Tag(soup, "td")
soup.insert(0, tag1)
tag1.insert(0, tag2)
tag2.insert(0, tag3)
for i in range(0,len(mem_attr)):
        tag3.insert(0,tag4)
        tag4.insert(i,mem_attr[i])

print soup.prettify()
```

Here is its output:

```
<html>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>
    Description
    PhysicalID
    Slot
    Size
    Width
   </th>
  </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

What I am looking for is this one.

```
<html>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <th>
        Description
       </th>
       <th>
        PhysicalID
       </th>
       <th>
        Slot
       </th>
       <th>
        Size
       </th>
       <th>
        Width
       </th>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </html>
```

Can anyone tell me what is missing in the code?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're putting it in the same `th`. You never told it to create more than one.

Here is code more like what you are wanting:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag
soup = BeautifulSoup()
mem_attr = ['Description', 'PhysicalID', 'Slot', 'Size', 'Width']
html = Tag(soup, "html")
table = Tag(soup, "table")
tr = Tag(soup, "tr")
soup.append(html)
html.append(table)
table.append(tr)
for attr in mem_attr:
    th = Tag(soup, "th")
    tr.append(th)
    th.append(attr)

print soup.prettify()
```

Comment: Can you be little more clear. I tried couple of things but that didnt work either. for example: I use this code under for loop: `tag3.insert(i,tag4)` but nothing worked.